# How can I dynamically populate the table layout in android Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to popualte tablelayout using webapi but getting error:

"The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Here is my code

allOrderRestaurent.axml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tblAllOrderRestaurent">
  <TableRow
      android:background="#ECEFF1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"       
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:text="Android Lollipop"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductname"
            />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="21"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

and here is my acitvity  code
AllOrderRestaurentActivity

```
public List<UserCartModel> mItems;
    TableLayout tablelayout;
    TextView productname, price;
    int sessionid;
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.allorderRestaurent);
        sessionid = Common.GetSessionValue();
        List<UserCartModel> mItems = await GetData();

        tablelayout = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.tblAllOrderRestaurent);
        productname = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtproductname);
        price = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtproductprice);
        BindData();
        // Create your application here
    }

    public async Task<List<UserCartModel>> GetData()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string ac = Common.Url;
        string url = ac + "RestaurentOderList?id=" + sessionid;

        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";

        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            mItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserCartModel>>(content);
        }
        return mItems;
    }

    public void BindData()
    {
        try
        {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

            foreach (var r in mItems)
            {

                productname = new TextView(this);
                productname.Text = r.ProductName;
                productname.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

                price = new TextView(this);
                price.Text = Convert.ToString(r.Price);
                price.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

                tableRow.AddView(price, 0);
                tableRow.AddView(price, 1);

                tablelayout.AddView(tableRow, 0);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error During Bind Table Layout All Order Restaurent" + exx.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Solved it by making following changes

```
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
```

Add this Code into Foreach loop And Add:

```
tableRow.RemoveAllViews();
```